# Trig Reduction With Pythagoras #2

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin 10^\circ = p$, then determine $$\sin 280^\circ$$ in terms of $p$.

$$\sin 280^\circ=\sin(180^\circ+100^\circ) = -\sin 100^\circ$$
$$-\sin 100^\circ = -\sin(90^\circ+10^\circ) = -\sin 10^\circ$$
$$ =-p $$
Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $$\sin(90^\circ\pm x)=\cos x$$

As $280^\circ$ lies in the third Quadrant where sine ratio is $\le0$

$$\implies\sin(280^\circ)=\sin(3\cdot90^\circ+10^\circ)=-\cos10^\circ$$

As the multiple of  $90^\circ$ is $3$ which is odd, the resultant ratio will be cosine

Comment: Ok. so how do I proceed after getting $-cos10$?

Comment: @user108104, As $0<10^\circ<90^\circ,\cos10^\circ>0$ hence $$=+\sqrt{1-\sin^210^\circ}$$

Comment: Which is $\sqrt{1-p^2}$?

Comment: @user108104, Yes. But, what is more important is the idea. Could you assimilate that?

Comment: Yes, What I understand is that $$-sin100 = cos 10$$ since 2 minuses will make it positive. If it was $sin100$ would it have been $-cos10$?

Answer (score 0):

sin(280)= sin(-80) = sin(10-90).

Comment: You are close.  A couple more steps to get there, starting with (say) the difference angle formula for sine.